# Translate int into string/Translate int into source

Tags: java, image, object, graphics, draw

I'm using:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Spot extends Rectangle{
    public int objectID;
    public int characterID;

public Spot(int x, int y, int width, int height, int objectID, int characterID){
    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    this.objectID = objectID;
    this.characterID = characterID;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon("pictures/objects/Object" +String.valueOf(objectID) +".png").getImage(), x, y, width, height, null);
    g.drawImage(Screen.Character[characterID], x, y, width, height, null);
}
```

}

The question is: This kind of code doesen't work. Why and what should I do to get it work? I read about translating that int into string. But I tried one method and it didn't seem to work for me.. This is what I tried

**EDIT**

So it doesen't work with

```
 new ImageIcon("pictures/objects/Object" +objectID +".png").getImage()
```

but it works like

```
 new ImageIcon("pictures/objects/Object1.png").getImage()
```

Even if the value of objectID is 1.

**Found it out**

It didn't work because I didn't really give objectID any value, as someone told.. :D Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work? Works fine for me if I compile it.

Comment: There's the whole code now, but still doesen't work